# Nodejs setTimeOut function

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I don't know how to use setTimeOut function in NodeJS. Let say I want:

1. a function A() to be called every 10 seconds.
2. if a function A return a result from callback of value 'true', it will call an URL and DONE!
3. if a function A keep returns a result from callback of value 'false', keep calling until it received 'YES' for 10 mins
4. if it reachs 10 mins max and there still no 'true' result, finally return 'false'

how do you do that in Node.js please!

Comment: Node.js setTimeout is exactly the same as regular browsers javascript setTimeout. Maybe post your example code what is not working.

Comment: Take a look at setInterval instead, it allows you to specify a function that will be called every X seconds. To remove it once your function is done, save a reference to the returned function and use clearInterval

Answer (score 0):

Simple example  (will probably need tweaking)

```
var timed_out = false,
    timer     = setTimeout(function() {
        timed_out = true;
    }, (1000*60*10)); // ten minutes passed


function A() {
    call_func(function(result) { // call func with callback
        if (result) {
             clearTimeout(timer);
             DONE();
        }else if (! timed_out ) {
            setTimeout(A, 10000); // call again in 10 seconds
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks @adeneo, when if (result), how do you clear the setTimeout to stop it?

Comment: @NamNguyen - I don't really see why you would have to clear any timeouts in that code, but I added it anyway.

Comment: I actually don't know if we have to clear it or not and what the best practice is. Thanks for your answer, it's very helpful.

Comment: @NamNguyen - You should generally clear timeouts, but in this case the recursive timeout is only 10 seconds, and it's not called if there is a result, so there's nothing to clear. The other timeout is running for ten minutes, but it's just one instance and it's irrelevant for performance and not called recursively, so it doesn't really have to be cancelled either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tenMinutes = false; // my boolean to test the 10 minutes
setTimeout(function() { tenMinutes = true; }, 600000); // a timeout to set the boolean to true when the ten minutes are gone

function A() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myURL",
        method: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function(myBool) {
            if (!myBool && !tenMinutes) { // if false, and not ten minutes yet, try again in ten seconds
                setTimeout(A, 10000);
            }
            else if (!myBool && tenMinutes) { // else, if still false, but already passed ten minutes, calls the fail function (simulates the return false)
                myFailresponse();
            }
            else { // if the AJAX response is true, calls the success function (simulates the return true)
                mySuccessResponse();
            }
        }
    });
}

function mySuccessResponse() {
    // you've got a "return true" from your AJAX, do stuff 
}

function myFailResponse() {
    // you've lots of "return false" from your AJAX for 10 minutes, do stuff 
}

A(); // call the A function for the first time
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. You can use setInterval to call the function regularly. If you get success, do success stuff and cancel the timer. Otherwise, just cancel the time when the limit is reached.

```
function a(){
  console.log('a called');
  return false;
}

var doThing = (function() {
    var start,
        timeout,
        delay = 1000,  // 1 second for testing
        limit = 10000; // 10 seconds for testing
    return function() {

      if (!start) {
        start = new Date().getTime();
        timeout = setInterval(doThing, delay);
      } 

      // Call a and tests return value
      if (a()) {

        // Do success stuff

        // Set start to 0 so timer is cancelled
        start = 0;
      }

      // stop timer if limit exceeded or start set to zero
      if ( new Date().getTime() > start + limit || !start) {
        timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
        start = null;
      }
  } 
}());

doThing();
```